# MongoDB - Project a nested object of of a recursive document structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, projection

After days of research I need some help. I want to find a nested object from within my recursive structured object:

```
{
  id: "1",
  model: {
    dataList: [
      {
        name: 'someName',
        semantic: ['unique','string','array']
        bitOffset: 1,
        bitLength: 16,
        subDataList:[
          {
            name: 'someName',
            semantic: ['also','unique','array']
            bitOffset: 1,
            bitLength: 16,
            subDataList:[
              {
                name: 'someName',
                semantic: ['even','more','unique']
                bitOffset: 1,
                bitLength: 16,
                subDataList:[...]
              },
              {...}
            ]
          },
          {...}
        ]
      },
      {...}
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to get one of the subDocuments from the query. For example this one:

```
   {
     name: 'someName',
     semantic: ['even','more','unique']
     bitOffset: 1,
     bitLength: 16,
     subDataList:[...]
   }
```

I don't want to get all the parents. Only the inner object with its children. I tried many variations of queries including `$where`, `$unwind`, `§replaceRoot`, `...` but I was not able to receive the desired nested document.

The identifier of the nested document is the semantic array. The combination of the array elements (always strings) is unique.

Any hints on how to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you specify which children you need ?

Comment: the 'semantic' array has unique content. so I have to check the array content

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
db.getCollection('model').aggregate([{
        $unwind: "$model.dataList"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$model.dataList.subDataList"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$model.dataList.subDataList.subDataList"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            subDataList: {
                $first: '$model.dataList.subDataList.subDataList'
            }
        }
    }
])
```